# Updating settings.php breaks website hosted from subfolder

Tags: 7, .htaccess, uri

This is somewhat linked to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78793/htaccess-issue-with-url-masking).  I have 2 Drupal 7 sites hosted in subfolders, one of which is intended to be a production site (`public_html/site1`) and the other is the testing site (`public_html/site1-test`).

The main url (i.e., site1.com) should be shown when accessing the production site.  When I go to my main url, it shows correctly.  However, all links and content are shown via the subfolder (e.g., `site1.com/site1/content/...` rather than `site1/content`).

To facilitate the change, I updated the `$base_url` variable in the settings.php file to serve the base URL (i.e., site1.com) and that completely breaks the site.  The theme stops showing, logins don't work, etc.

Is there a way around this problem?  The main site should mask off the subfolder in the url, however I don't think I can do that without updating the `$base_url`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your base URL in settings.php like

```
$base_url = 'http://site1.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

And in your .htaccess file set RewriteBase to:

```
RewriteBase /site1
```

or

```
RewriteBase /site1-test
```

Comment: Didn't work...site was still broken.

Comment: I have actually tried this answer in the past, so I assume its a common fix.  If this still breaks site functionality, do you know if the problem is htaccess-related, or Drupal-related?